# Remove non duplicates from 2 array

Tags: php, arrays

I didn't find much resource online about this. I have 2 array. I want to remove all the items that doesn't exists on the other array.

*Array 1*

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "download"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "test"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "edit"
}
```

*Array 2*

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "download"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "{category}"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "edit"
}
```

So the final array I should be getting is something like

```
 array(3) {
          [0]=>
          string(8) "download"
          [2]=>
          string(4) "edit"
    }
```

Comment: http://php.net/array_intersect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array_intersect()` is what you need:

```
<?php
    $array1 = array("download", "test", "edit");
    $array2 = array("download", "category", "edit");
    $array3 = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
    var_dump($array3);
?>
```

More here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 2):

you can use the array_diff function described [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$array3 = array_diff($array1, $array2)
```

would be all the elements that occur in array1 that do not also occur in array2

For finding overlaps, you can use the similar [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function

Answer (score 0):

You can use function [array_intersect_ukey](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-ukey.php).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with 2 foreach :

```
<?php
$array1 = array("download", "test", "edit");
$array2 = array("download", "category", "edit");
$array3 = array();

foreach($array1 as $value){
    foreach($array2 as $value2){
        if($value === $value2){
            $array3[] = $value;
            break;
        }
    }
}

print_r($array3);
```